# Cypress bad gateway

Tags: cypress

I have started my app locally and reach it fine on http://localhost:3000
But when trying to access it throuhg the cypress tool I get 502 bad gateway. Anyone knows why this differ from it working just fine in Chrome to access it?

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same issue when running Angular app in localhost. App was running in chrome but not in cypress tool giving 502 bad gateway error. I builded the angular app by ng-build command and served using command http-server -p 4200 -c-1 dist/your_poject_name. When running http-server command, got as below:
Starting up http-server, serving dist
Available on:

http://10.132.14.98:4200

http://127.0.0.1:4200

Use the url http://10.132.14.98:4200 in cy.visit and now bad gateway error does not come. The problem is with using 127.0.0.1 or localhost in the url. Anything other than localhost and 127.0.0.1 works. Hope this information helps.